# Apply background style effect in camera app

Tags: android, android-camera

[image]

I have a code for taking pictures. Then how to apply photo effect like above picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use android aviary sdk for image effects.

http://www.aviary.com/android

Look at here for [Documentation](http://www.aviary.com/android-documentation).